# Provide an example of a locally Euclidean, paracompact Hausdorff space but not have a countable basis.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

Anyone can give the example? It is an exercise of Boothby's Manifolds book.

Comment: Do you know how the assumptions play together with connectedness?

Comment: Sorry...I don't know. So connectedness plays an important role in the example?

Comment: What Daniel is getting at is that a connected paracompact Hausdorff space that is locally Euclidean is second countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perfectly good example would be an uncountable space with the discrete topology. If you want something slightly less trivial, take the Cartesian product of this space with any locally Euclidean, paracompact Hausdorff space.

Comment: Well...I know it. Thanks.